# Bamboo tests failing could not find test report

Tags: macos, jasmine, bamboo

I am getting failure when running a test:

Error summary for Default Job
The job generated some errors, drill down into the full build log for more details.
Could not find test result reports in the /Users/su/Downloads/BambooInstallationDirectory/C: /Users/su/Downloads/BambooHome directory/xml-data/build-dir/GSWB-FIR-JOB1 directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this was because the wrong path was given in the bamboo-init.properties.

Even though I changed the correct path to Bamboo Home directory it didn't work.

That's because for the changes to take effect you need to restart your bamboo.

bin/stop-bamboo.sh
bin/start-bamboo.sh

and start from scratch